# How can i render a string from database to web grid with out the html tags and also have it truncated.using mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

How can i render a string from database to web grid with out the html tags and also have it truncated.razor engine

Answer (score 0):

Note the grid.column with the format in it:

http://www.nickharris.net/2010/10/a-first-look-at-the-asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid/

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })),
```

so you want something like

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => item.Trim().Replace(.whatever to remove your tags..)),
```

I don't know exactly how you want tags removed. Do you want it html encoded, completely removed, etc. but this should start you off.